# Iterate over win_disk_facts result appended with empty dict along with result

Tags: ansible

I am trying to iterate over available disks and fetch few details. I use `win_disk_facts` to get all the disks present on the host, then I manage to loop and append the results to `mdisk` dict variable.

I am getting the intended Json output from debug but the result is also getting appended with empty dict `{}` at the beginning of my json result.

I am sure the problem is with the syntax but I don't get how to append only the json dict excluding empty dict `{}`, first occurrence is empty dict as in output shown here .

Code:

```yaml
- name: get disk
  win_disk_fact:

- name:
  set_fact:
    mdisk: "{{mdisk|d({})}},
           {
           'name': '{{ item | json_query('friendly_name') }}',
           'Firmware_version': '{{ item | json_query('firmware_version') }}'
            }"
  loop: "{{ ansible_disks }}"
```

Output:

```json
"ansible_facts": {
        "diskfact": [
            [
                {},
                {
                    " friendly_name": "abcde",
                    "firmware_version": "x1y2z3"
                }
            ],
            {
                " friendly_name ": "xyze",
                "'firmware_version'": "2341"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats IMO a lot of complexity for something that can get as simple as:

```yaml
- name: print out the needed information
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg:
      - disk name is {{ item.friendly_name }}
      - firmware version is {{ item.firmware_version }}
  loop: "{{ ansible_disks }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.friendly_name }}"
```

I used `debug` in the above example but you can use that loop in any other task.

If for some reason (that we cannot guess from your question and that I really have a hard time to understand...) you really need to transform the variable name, some of the key names and the number of keys inside each item, you can still keep the KISS principle (although it makes by itself things too complex compared to using the original var directly IMO).

```yaml
- name: make a var out of an other var
  vars:
    query: '[].{"name": "friendly_name", "firmware_version": "firmware_version"}'
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    mdisk: "{{ ansible_disks | json_query(query) }}"
```

---

Now to answer your direct question if you still want to do the above transformation and construct the variable through an iteration, you can. But this is in all respect the least efficient scenario.

```yaml
- name: make a var out of an other var
  vars:
    current_disk:
      name: "{{ item.friendly_name }}"
      firmware_version: "{{ item.firmware_version }}"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    mdisk: "{{ mdisk | d([]) + [current_disk] }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_disks }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.friendly_name }}"
```

Meanwhile, note that `ansible_disks` and `mdisk` are lists (of dict elements) and not dicts.

Comment: Thnks alot for your detailed explanation/suggestions.To clarfy about the var names,i am trying to match my DB attribute names here.Json result frm this code will be posted to my Database via api ,that’s where I am trying to assign it to a new variable name. And I am a newbie here trying with lists ,dictionary’s .I tried the changes you suggested , first option is working fine for me and second option is giving empty results    “mdisk”: “” . Third option suggested is giving    msg: unexpected templating type error ({{ mdisk | d([]) + [disk_info]}}) can only concatenate str (not\”list\”)to str .

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: I tried with 2.13.2.

Comment: For the second option, there was a typo in the initial var name (fixed). For the last (and, I insist, **worse** option), I guess that `mdisk` is already declared somewhere in your environment as a string while it should be undefined when you first enter the loop (or at least should be a list). [Full run with what I guess is your initial variable structure](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/87727f8d2d00ee90a6b5de545c604749). For your next question, please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Specifically in this question, the initial example data structure is missing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot , all 3 are working now . And thank u  for your patience in assisting and  sharing the required links .